# shader replaces texture of all meshes - opengl

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, libgdx, glsl, shader

Image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/scgKk.png

Hi, I have 3 objects/modelinstances that are being rendered in my scene:

- Model A
  -Rectangle
  -Blue box texture
- Model B
  -Rectangle
  -Red box texture
- Model C
  -Square
  -smiley face texture

But my code makes it so that it draws all of them with the "latest" drawn mesh's texture, hence why in the picture, all 3 of them are drawn with the same texture.

My fragment code:

```
#ifdef GL_ES 
precision mediump float;
#endif

varying vec2 v_texCoord0;
uniform sampler2D sampler;

void main() {
gl_FragColor = vec4(v_texCoord0, 0.0, 1.0);
vec4 tex = texture2D (sampler, v_texCoord0);
gl_FragColor = tex;
}
```

So here are my questions with shaders:

- What causes this?
- Do I need to have 1 instance of a shader per 1 instance of a modelInstance?
- Can a single shader render multiple meshes, where each mesh has a different texture?
- If so with above, how do you get past the 32 texture limit for a shader?

edit:

Just found out that whenever I bind a texture, all of the models will use that texture. So the most latest binded texture is the one that everyone uses

Comment: The shader has very little to do with it. What matters is which texture is bound at the time you make the draw calls, to the texture unit set as the value of the sampler. So the code you posted has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Before calling gldraw...() for every model you have to rebind the correct texture to the shaders. So you call: glbindtexture(textureA) gldraw(modelA), glbindtexture(textureB) gldraw(modelB), ....